# Wordpress Sub Menu Font Size

Tags: wordpress, plugins, submenu, megamenu

I have used the following css to increase the font size of my "Main" sub menu headings (MegaMenu No Link Titles) - using this code:

```
nav.std-menu ul.sub-menu {
    font-size: 18px!important;
}
```

That works great on desktop / iPad Views, however my code for mobile is not changing the font size to 18 as done on my desktop version. 
This is the code I have tried:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    nav.std-menu ul.sub-menu {
        font-size: 18px!important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the problem you have given there is now answer possible which is more specific than this:

It looks like your code on mobile is not working as there are more specific CSS selectors which overwrite your template code and/or it is not the same menu.

Use a tool like firebug or the Google Chrome debugger console to find out where the font-size is set in order to define a more specific one.